# Making sortable table after first loading data into table using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a table without page refresh using:

```
<script>
function example_ajax_request() {
  $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0" /></p>');
  $('#example-placeholder').load("get_data.php");
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="example_ajax_request()" value="Click Me!" />
<div id="example-placeholder"></div>
```

Where the get_data.php returns a table in the correct format ie/

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 <thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to make this table sortable using the jquery plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ but am having some difficulty.

If i copy and paste my table data onto the page directly and load the page the plugin works so
I'm guessing it has something to so with my $(document).ready(function() ????

Any help to get my table sortable would be awesome!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call tablesorter on the div once its populated.

```
$('#example-placeholder').load("get_data.php");
$('#example-placeholder').tablesorter();
```

Comment: Tried doing that and it's still not loading for me.... here's the full code: (my table id is "myTable")

$(document).ready(function() 
    {         
       $("#myTable").tablesorter();  
    } 
);

function example_ajax_request() {
  $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0" /></p>');
  $('#example-placeholder').load("get_data.php");
  $("#myTable").trigger("update");    
}

Comment: Oh god. Could just post a sample page on the internet somewhere? It's much easier to debug with firebug when there's a working page to hit.